# Сохранить Cookies после закрытия браузера

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста.Есть такой скрипт

```
<?

if (!isset($_SESSION["lang"]))
{
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"]))
    {
        $langs=explode('-',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $lang=preg_replace('/;.*$/','',$langs[0]);
        $lang=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z_\-]/','',$lang);

        $cookie_set = setcookie ("lan", $lang, time()+60*60*24*30);
        $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["lang"] = $_COOKIE["lang"];
    }
}

if ($_SESSION["lang"] == 'ru')
{
    require_once('language/ru/dict.php');
}
else if ($_SESSION["lang"] == 'ua')
{
    require_once('language/ua/dict.php');
}
else
{
    require_once('language/en/dict.php');
}
?>
```

Все работает замечательно, только вот когда закрываешь браузер и открываешь заново, то выбранный язык слитает на первоначальный, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сохранить куки даже после закрытия браузера.

Comment: setcookie ("lan**g**", $lang, time()+60*60*24*30);

Comment: @flax 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\test1.ru\www\feed.php:8) in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\classes\lang.php on line 12
выдает такую ошибку.А то видимо проглядел спасибо.

Comment: @flax Все ошибку убрал, просто не там подключил, но все равно почему то после закрытия браузера не сохраняет выбранный язык.

Comment: Смотрите в браузере какое значение Expires получилось у куки.